# Is it possible to have more than three saved games in Super Mario 3D Land?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

Is there any way to have more than 3 saved games in Super Mario 3D Land?  My wife and kids have claimed all three saved game slots, and I'd like to play sometime...

The 3DS has an SD card, so it seems like it ought to have lots of storage, but I don't see any way to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Super Mario 3D Land does not support any more than 3 save slots. The SD card does hold save data for many games, but you cannot add to save slots or anything like that.

Answer (score -4):

Put in another SD card and put your save on there.

Check https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41052/17862 to ensure you use the right SD cards.

Comment: That's incorrect. Cart games saves are on the cart itself. The only data saved on the SD card is media (photos/videos/music) and downloadable games.